# stored procedure that sends an email alert after an invalid character is inserted into a specific column

Tags: email, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will send an email to me when or after an invalid character is inserted into a particular column. I've already come up with some of the script to create it but I think I am missing something as it keeps giving me errors. I also already identified the invalid character to be the Grave Accent character so I've tried to use that so when that character is input I get notified.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InvalidCharacterCheck
AS
IF ((SELECT * FROM StudentNames WHERE LastName like '%`%') like '%' + '`' + '%')
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
         @recipients = 'Notifyme@gmail.com',
         @subject = 'The LastName column has a record with the grave accent invalid character'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'There is no invalid character in the LastName column at present'
END
```

Comment: `it keeps giving me errors` And the error message is ?

Comment: OK for that particular script i came up with it gives this ------- Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InvalidCharacterCheck, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0]
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Other options are triggers ON INSERT and do your check there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure
    AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @errorCount INT;

SELECT
    @errorCount = COUNT(FirstName)
FROM
    StudentNames
WHERE
    FirstName like '%`%'
    OR LastName like '%`%'

IF (@errorCount > 0) 
BEGIN 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'Notifyme@gmail.com',
    @subject = 'The LastName column has a record with the grave accent invalid character' 
END 
ELSE
BEGIN 
    PRINT 'There is no invalid character in the LastName column at present' 
END
END
GO
```

However I would look at prevention rather than cure, and sanitise the data before it gets inserted into the table.  You dont want to have to clean up a mess, just dont create it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked like an absolute charm. I agree there should be measures in place however organisation has decided that will be handled at application level where they'll need to put in some rules of some sort to parse the user input data. All they wanted from DBA standpoint at this time was an alert. Appreciate the assist